# How to print many invoices using crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, crystal-reports

I want to print invoices and each invoice has its own products. I use stored procedures to get the data. I want to print the invoice with all its details on a page followed by the other invoice on the next page, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what is the problem.

If it's the need to start each invoice on a new page, then Group the report on Invoice number and set the Group Footer property of 'New Page After'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the details section of your report for that.
In the details section add the recurring fields from your data source and create the the form of your invoice. It will automatically repeat everything from the section (elements and all) with each row returned from the data source.
Depending on the page setup you can have multiple invoices on one page as well as on separate pages.

Hope this helped but you need to be more precise with your questions.